# Gauss Elimination C++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, matrix, segmentation-fault, gaussian

I'm really stuck with my code for Gauss Elimination in C++, I need to return upper triangular matrix but still only thing I get is Segmentation fault. I know there must be some sort of going of allocated memory but I can't find where.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double ** allocateDynamicArray(int order){
    double ** dynArray = new double *[order];
    int cols = order+1;
    double *pool = new double [order * cols];
    for(int i = 0;i < order; i++, pool += cols){
           dynArray[i] = pool;
    }
    return dynArray;
}

void deallocateDynamicArray(double **dynArray){
    delete [] dynArray[0];
        delete [] dynArray;
}

void addAndPrintArray(double **dynArray, int order){
    cout << "Zadejte prvky pole radu " << order << endl;
    for(int i=0; i< order; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< order+1; j++){
            cout << "Pole[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> dynArray[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i< order; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< order+1; j++){

            if(dynArray[i][j] < 10 && dynArray[i][j] >= 0){
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << dynArray[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

double ** gaussElimination(double** dynArray, int order){
    for(int j=1; j<=order; j++) /*Horni trojuhelnikova matice*/
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=order; i++)
        {
            if(i>j)
            {
                double c=dynArray[i][j]/dynArray[j][j];

                for(int k=1; k<=order+1; k++)
                {
                    dynArray[i][k] = dynArray[i][k] - c * dynArray[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dynArray;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Zadejte rad matice: ";
    int order;
    cin >> order;
    double **arr = allocateDynamicArray(order);
    addAndPrintArray(arr, order);
    gaussElimination(arr, order);
    deallocateDynamicArray(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: can you please use `gdb` to get some more info for us?

Comment: It would be a better question if you would limit the code we have to look at, by debugging your code as far as you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in C/C++ the first element of an array should have index `0`, so your

```
for(int i=1; i<=order; i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=0; i<order; i++)
```

in the `gaussElimination` function.